# how do i delete all roles from a server without an error?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

my question is how to delete ALL roles
code:

```
message.guild.roles.cache.forEach(role => role.delete())
```

error:

```
DiscordAPIError: Invalid Role
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code would work fine, but...

1. You cannot delete @everyone.
2. You can not delete bot roles.
3. You cannot delete roles higher than the bot's.

So, here's the working code:

```js
message.guild.roles.cache.forEach(role => {
    let botHighestRole = message.guild.member(bot.user.id).roles.highest;
    let isBotRoleHigher = role.comparePositionTo(botHighestRole)<0;
    if (role.name !== "@everyone" && isBotRoleHigher && !role.managed) {
        role.delete();
    }
})
```

[Role#comparePositionTo()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=comparePositionTo)

[Role#managed](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=managed)

Comment: No problem. Please don't forget to mark my answer correct by clicking on the checkmark.